# Each method in jquery

Tags: jquery

Hi I have two span in one div. I want to hide this `.sp` div on click on `#hidemain` but I need to check for a condition :
`both span should be hidden`.
 Currently when I run my function it hides the **main div** when there is only one span hidden.

```
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('a#firsta').click(function(){
                $('#one').hide();
            });

            $('a#firstb').click(function(){
                $('#two').hide();
            });

            $('a#hidemain').click(function(){
                $('.sp').find('span').each(function(){
                    if($(this).is(':hidden')){
                        $('.sp').hide();
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="sp">
        Main
        <span id="one">fist</span>
        <span id="two">Second</span>
    </div>

    <a href="#" id="hidemain">hide main</a><br>
    <a href="#" id="firsta">hide first</a><br>
    <a href="#" id="firstb">hide Second</a>
</body>
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly

Comment: Can you update the question so that it makes sense?

Comment: What is want if I click "hide main" it should hide div if both span under this div is hidden

Comment: please see example code http://jsbin.com/welcome/70806/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $('a#hidemain').click(function(){
     if(!$('.sp').find('span:visible').length) {
        $('.sp').hide();
     };
 });
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TKseR/)

What it does is look for a visible span under your root element. If it doesn't find any, then it hides the div.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for this:

```
 $('a#hidemain').click(function() {
     $('.sp').hide();
     $('.sp').find('span').each(function() {
         if(!$(this).is(':hidden')) {
              $('.sp').show();
         }
     });
 });
```

Comment: can you please elaborate the `if` part. This makes totally not sense

Comment: on click on $('a#hidemain'). it should hide $('.sp') but if both span should be hidden. else it will not supposed to hide it

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, you need to hide the div `.sp` only if both `span` are hidden. In this code, I first hide the div irrespective of the state of the `span` elements and then go through each span and if any of them is visible, I make the div visible again. So the final result is that the div is hidden only if both `span` elements are hidden.

Comment: Aside from the fact that I don't like to hide something just to show it again, you could improve your loop by adding a `return false` to your `if` block. That will cause `.each` to skip the rest of the elements. Since you only need to find *one* non-hidden element.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you want to hide the `<div>`, but only when all `<span>`'s inside it are hidden as well. Correct?

Here's how you can do that:

```
$(function () {
    $('a#firsta').on('click', function(e) {
        $('#one').hide();
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('a#firstb').on('click', function(e) {
        $('#two').hide();
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('a#hidemain').on('click', function(e) {
        if ($('div.sp span').filter(':visible').length === 0) {
            $('div.sp').hide();
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NETKf/